# Reduce repetition in Pandas DataFrame column assignments

Tags: python, pandas

Could the aggregate functions after using grouping functions like groupby() and resample() be looped for cleaner code

____DateTime.____    |  Steps  | day_segment
2017-10-25 00:00:00| 4  | night
2017-10-25 00:01:00| 7  | night
2017-10-25 00:02:00| 10 | night
2017-10-25 00:03:00| 26 | night
.
.
.
2017-10-25 10:04:00| 80 | morning
2017-10-25 10:05:00| 45 | morning
2017-10-25 10:06:00| 53 | morning

### DataFrame: data

```py
day_segments = ['morning','afternoon','evening','night']
#all_steps is a list input from the user
all_steps = ['sumallsteps','maxallsteps','minallsteps','avgallsteps','stdallsteps']
finalDataset = pd.DataFrame()

#Descriptive Statistics Features:
for day_segment in day_segments:
    resampledData = pd.DataFrame()
    resampledData = data.loc[data['day_segment'] == str(day_segment)]
    if("sumallsteps" in all_steps):
        finalDataset["step_" + str(day_segment) + "_sumallsteps"] = resampledData['steps'].resample('D').sum()

    if("maxallsteps" in all_steps):
        finalDataset["step_" + str(day_segment) + "_maxallsteps"] = resampledData['steps'].resample('D').max()

    if("minallsteps" in all_steps):
        finalDataset["step_" + str(day_segment) + "_minallsteps"] = resampledData['steps'].resample('D').min()

    if("avgallsteps" in all_steps):
        finalDataset["step_" + str(day_segment) + "_avgallsteps"] = resampledData['steps'].resample('D').mean()

    if("stdallsteps" in all_steps):
        finalDataset["step_" + str(day_segment) + "_stdallsteps"] = resampledData['steps'].resample('D').std()
    finaDataset.to_csv('data'+str(day_segment)+'.csv',index=True)
```

### IS THERE A WAY TO MAKE THE 'IF' STATEMENTS AND ITS FUNCTIONS SHORTER? LOOP IT IN A DICTIONARY SOMEHOW?

There are more assignments like this in my code so I would want to know if there is a way I could just loop the aggregate functions

Comment: Using agg() you could loop through the all_steps and aggregate functions using a dict

Comment: Add more context where you iterate over `day_segment` list

Comment: @WillacyMe great! I will look into agg()

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest just added a loop!

Comment: @EchhitJoshi: But your loop does not really do as you would expect, all day segments use exactly the same data. In contrast to e.g. the morning using only the, you know, morning. That sounds to me like your code is not yet finished?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Comment: @Graipher Sorry for the confusion, I added a 'day segment' column so now we can loop through the 'day_segments' list and subset data and process it. I wanted to know if all the 'if' statements which look similar can be done in a couple of lines without the repetition as is.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thank you Toby! I added some more context. I still do not know how to exactly word the question/title, I will as soon as I think of a way exactly pinpoint the problem in a couple of words

Answer (score 4):

Try to get a good book or tutorial about pandas. The things you want to do is relatively easy with `groupby.agg`

```
for segment, segment_data in df.groupby("day_segment"):
    aggregated_data = segment_data.resample("D").agg(
        ["sum", "mean", "std", "min", "max"]
    )
    aggregated_data_renamed = aggregated_data.copy()
    aggregated_data_renamed.columns = aggregated_data.columns.droplevel(0).map(
        lambda x: f"step_{segment}_{x}allsteps"
    )

    filename = f"data{segment}.csv"
    aggregated_data_renamed.to_csv(filename, index=True)
```

This uses `mean` instead of `avg`. If this is a problem, you can add another rename function call somewhere

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want can be done by using `groupby` correctly.

First, let's generate some sample data:

```
def to_seconds(t):
    return (t.hour * 60 + t.minute) * 60 + t.second

labels = ["night", "morning", "afternoon", "evening"]
bins = to_seconds(pd.to_datetime(["00:00:00", "06:00:00", "12:00:00", "18:00:00", "23:59:59"]))

date = pd.date_range("2020-02-01 00:00:00", "2020-02-03 23:59:59", freq="H")
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": date, "steps": np.random.randint(0, 100, len(date))})
df["day_segment"] = pd.cut(to_seconds(df.date.dt), bins, labels=labels, right=False)
#                   date  steps day_segment
# 0  2020-02-01 00:00:00      8       night
# 1  2020-02-01 01:00:00     43       night
# 2  2020-02-01 02:00:00     23       night
# 3  2020-02-01 03:00:00     84       night
# 4  2020-02-01 04:00:00     32       night
# ..                 ...    ...         ...
# 67 2020-02-03 19:00:00     36     evening
# 68 2020-02-03 20:00:00     76     evening
# 69 2020-02-03 21:00:00     51     evening
# 70 2020-02-03 22:00:00     99     evening
# 71 2020-02-03 23:00:00      4     evening
```

And then you just need to group by `(date, day_segment)`:

```
df.groupby([date.date, "day_segment"]).steps.agg(["sum", "max", "min", "std", "mean"])
#                         sum  max  min        std       mean
#            day_segment                                     
# 2020-02-01 night        263   84    8  29.403515  43.833333
#            morning      243   91    1  39.943710  40.500000
#            afternoon    364   88   28  26.919633  60.666667
#            evening      247   99    0  32.021347  41.166667
# 2020-02-02 night        300   90    1  33.148152  50.000000
#            morning      278   96    1  37.011710  46.333333
#            afternoon    340   97   25  28.465183  56.666667
#            evening      418   95    9  33.773757  69.666667
# 2020-02-03 night        458   92   60  13.894843  76.333333
#            morning      211   68   15  21.949184  35.166667
#            afternoon    426   95   36  21.042814  71.000000
#            evening      281   99    4  36.207274  46.833333
```

The list of aggregation functions can be built from the user input via some dictionary translation and the writing to file can be done by filtering on the day_segment:

```
stats.reset_index(level=0).loc["evening"]
#                 level_0  sum  max  min        std       mean
# day_segment                                                 
# evening      2020-02-01  247   99    0  32.021347  41.166667
# evening      2020-02-02  418   95    9  33.773757  69.666667
# evening      2020-02-03  281   99    4  36.207274  46.833333
```